# Numpy: rewrite outer product and addition of the diagonal in vector form

Tags: python, numpy

Assume `X` is:

```
X = np.asarray(
   [0.5, 0.5],
   [0.87070241, 0.12929759],
   [0.97738616, 0.02261384],
   [0.99200957, 0.00799043]], dtype=np.float32)
```

For every row, I want to have a turn a row into a diagonal matrix and subtract from it the outer product as follows:

```
np.diagflat(X[i, :]) - np.outer(X[i, :], X[i, :])
```

for any index `i`.

Of course, I can just write a for-loop over `i` but is there a way to do it in the vectorized form?

I figured out that, it seems, I can rewrite the part I subtract as:

```
X.T[:, None, :] * X.T[None, :]
```

But still no clue how to properly add there `diagflat` or its equivalent without adding a for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more readable way, but:

```
(np.eye(2) * X[:, np.newaxis]) - (X[:, np.newaxis]) * X[..., np.newaxis]
```

Should do what you want.

**EDIT:** Changed from my initial answer of `(np.eye(2)[np.newaxis] - X[:, np.newaxis]) * X[..., np.newaxis]` after correction from OP.

Comment: You've missed a small part but the idea is correct and has led me to what I need. I've just changed it to `(np.eye(2) * X[:, np.newaxis]) - (X[:, np.newaxis]) * X[..., np.newaxis]`.

Comment: Got it, changed the answer in case anyone else stumbles on this.